# Is there a way to configure azure iot hub to allow public inbound traffic but only allow provate outbound traffic

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Like mentioned in the title, I would like to configure my azure iot hub to allow public inbound traffic but only allow private outbound traffic.

My current infrastructure is that an iot device will send data to my iot hub through the public endpoint, and from there the iot huh will privately send the data to a stream analytics job to process the data and send it to a sql database

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, you can configure Azure IoT Hub to allow public inbound traffic but only allow private outbound traffic. You can do this by using network security groups (NSGs) and Azure firewall in your IoT Hub network topology. You can create an NSG that only allows incoming traffic from specific IP addresses or ranges, and another NSG that allows outgoing traffic to specific destinations. Additionally, you can use Azure Firewall to restrict outgoing traffic from your IoT Hub to the internet and only allow traffic to specific Azure services.

I followed the steps to allow public inbound traffic and only allow private outbound traffic using Azure IOT hub.

- Create a IoT Hub by giving your resource group name and subscription name.

[image]

- Go to IoT Hub>Networking>Public access>Ip filter and add the IP address

[image]

- For private endpoint connections create a new end point and select to save it.

[image]

- Create network Security group with your resource group name and Subscription name

[image]

- Add inbound Security rules and Outbound Security rules by changing the Source port ranges it will be applied to resource.

[image]

- Create an SQL Database by giving your resource group name, Subscription name.

[image]

- Go to SQL Database which you created go to public access and save.

[image]

- For private endpoint connections create a new end point and select to save it.

[image]